# Tooltip arrow at top right of the div in CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, tooltip

I need to show an arrow which can be created using css on the top right of the div. And the arrow should be with continuous gradient of the div.

I have written css for arrow but it is not working.

Arrow should be facing to the top.

Here is my demo
http://jsfiddle.net/n5vK5/3/

Comment: Can you also post the *relevant* CSS and markup here please? That way the question is self-contained!

Comment: I have seen the link, but still I found this difficult to understand, could you elaborate your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the overflow:auto;

http://jsfiddle.net/n5vK5/7/

Comment: do you want the arrow outside of box

Comment: Yes arrow should be out of the box.

Comment: It is working but how can I give gradient for this arrow and border of 1px in black color?

Comment: you can't give gradient for this arrow because it is made from border and for border add box-shadow